# Tipos de Dados Inválidos

Tags: sql, oracle, tabela-html, tipagem

Estou tentando criar uma tabela no meu banco de dados, porém está dando erro de tipos de dados inválidos

Script da minha tabela:

```
create table Venda
(
  cod_Venda number(5)not null,
  DataVenda DATE,
  Hora TIME,
  cod_Comanda number(5)not null,
  constraint PK_cod_Venda_Venda PRIMARY KEY(cod_Venda)
);
```

Erro:

> Erro na Linha de Comandos : 486 Coluna : 8
>      Relatório de erros -
>      Erro de SQL: ORA-00902: tipo de dados inválido
>      00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
>      *Cause:
>      *Action:
>      submetido a commit.

Estou usando SQL Developer. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Já tentou remover o (5) da frente do number?

Comment: Use DATE na declaração, para o campo HORA.

Comment: Use DATE na DataVenda e grave a data e a hora , não precisando de um campo para a HORA.

Answer (score 1):

Não existe o tipo de dados Time em Oracle. Os campos date guardam século, dia, mes, ano , horas minutos e segundos.